# Oauth 2 popup with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, oauth, typescript, angular

I'm upgrading/rewriting an existing angular app to use angular2. My problem is that I want to open a OAuth flow in a new pop up window and once the OAuth flow is completed use window.postMessage to communicate back to the angular 2 app that the OAuth flow was successful.

Currently what I have is in the angular 2 service is

```
export class ApiService { 
    constructor(private _loggedInService: LoggedInService) {
        window.addEventListener('message', this.onPostMessage, false);
     }

    startOAuthFlow() {
       var options = 'left=100,top=10,width=400,height=500';
       window.open('http://site/connect-auth', , options);
    }

    onPostMessage(event) {
      if(event.data.status === "200") {
          // Use an EventEmitter to notify the other components that user logged in
          this._loggedInService.Stream.emit(null);
      }
    }

}
```

This template that is loaded at the end of the OAuth flow

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OAuth callback</title>
    <script>
      var POST_ORIGIN_URI = 'localhost:8000';
      var message = {"status": "200", "jwt":"2"};
      window.opener.postMessage(message, POST_ORIGIN_URI);
      window.close();
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Using `window.addEventListener` like this seems to completely break the angular 2 app, dereferencing `this`.

So my question is can I use window.addEventListener or should I not use postMessage to communicate back to the angular2 app?

** Complete angular2 noob so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with a bit of investigation found out the problem. I was de-referencing  `this`. This [github wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) helped me understand it a bit more.

To solve it for my case needed to do a couple of things. Firstly I created a service that encapsulated the adding of an eventListener

```
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

export class PostMessageService {
   dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
   addPostMessageListener(fn: EventListener): void {
     this.dom.getGlobalEventTarget('window').addEventListener('message', fn,false)
   }
}
```

Then using this `addPostMessageListener` I can attach a function in my other service to fire

```
constructor(public _postMessageService: PostMessageService,
    public _router: Router) {
    // Set up a Post Message Listener
    this._postMessageService.addPostMessageListener((event) => 
          this.onPostMessage(event)); // This is the important as it means I keep the reference to this

}
```

Then it works how I expected keeping the reference to this

Comment: any idea how this can be done now that `BrowserDomAdapter` is no longer exported in Angular 2 RCs?

Comment: update: actually, you can just use `window.addEventListener` -- the important part, as you point out, is using the anonymous function to preserve the execution context.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, is it possible that If receive message from same machine but different port ?  I want to send data from my jsp/java (8080 port) to angular2 listener(4200 port)..

Answer (score 6):

I have a complete Angular2 OAuth2 skeleton application on Github that you can refer to.

It makes use of an Auth service for OAuth2 Implicit grants that in turn uses a Window service to create the popup window.  It then monitors that window for the access token on the URL.

You can access the [demo OAuth2 Angular code (with Webpack) here](https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack).

Here is the login routine from the Auth service, which will give you an idea of what's going on without having to look at the entire project. I've added a few extra comments in there for you.

```
public doLogin() {
    var loopCount = this.loopCount;
    this.windowHandle = this.windows.createWindow(this.oAuthTokenUrl, 'OAuth2 Login');

    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (loopCount-- < 0) { // if we get below 0, it's a timeout and we close the window
            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
            this.emitAuthStatus(false);
            this.windowHandle.close();
        } else { // otherwise we check the URL of the window
            var href:string;
            try {
                href = this.windowHandle.location.href;
            } catch (e) {
                //console.log('Error:', e);
            }
            if (href != null) { // if the URL is not null
                var re = /access_token=(.*)/;
                var found = href.match(re);
                if (found) { // and if the URL has an access token then process the URL for access token and expiration time
                    console.log("Callback URL:", href);
                    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
                    var parsed = this.parse(href.substr(this.oAuthCallbackUrl.length + 1));
                    var expiresSeconds = Number(parsed.expires_in) || 1800;

                    this.token = parsed.access_token;
                    if (this.token) {
                        this.authenticated = true;
                    }

                    this.startExpiresTimer(expiresSeconds);
                    this.expires = new Date();
                    this.expires = this.expires.setSeconds(this.expires.getSeconds() + expiresSeconds);

                    this.windowHandle.close();
                    this.emitAuthStatus(true);
                    this.fetchUserInfo();
                }
            }
        }
    }, this.intervalLength);
}
```

Feel free to ask if you have any questions or problems getting the app up and running.

Comment: I'm getting an error thrown by Chrome on the line `href = this.windowHandle.location.href;` and the error says `Error: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:[PORT]" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` - am I the only one? Has Chrome updated their security policy since this post ?

Comment: @[Michael Oryl] can this be used for authorization grant flow?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the Angular2 way:

(Dart code but TS should be quite similar)

```dart
@Injectable()
class SomeService {
  DomAdapter dom;
  SomeService(this.dom) {
    dom.getGlobalEventTarget('window').addEventListener("message", fn, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me get to my solution!

Comment: I think maybe this is now  addGlobalEventListener('window',  'message', fn).. see     https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/EventManager

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with this for ages but in the end, the most robust way for me was to redirect the user to the oath page

```
window.location.href = '/auth/logintwitter';
```

do the oath dance in the backend (I used express) and then redirect back to a receiving front end page...

```
res.redirect(`/#/account/twitterReturn?userName=${userName}&token=${token}`);
```

There are some idiosyncracies to my solution because e.g. I wanted to use only JsonWebToken on the client regardless of login type, but if you are interested, whole solution is here.

https://github.com/JavascriptMick/learntree.org